# React Native run error: “Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65”

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I’m trying to run my React Native project using the `npm run ios` command.
But it does not work again and again because of some problem.
The error messages it prints out are shown below.

```
GetRest@0.0.1 ios /Users/user/Documents/w_space/bo.git/getrest

react-native run-ios

error Could not find the following native modules: RNSVG, RNSVG. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?

info Found Xcode workspace "GetRest.xcworkspace"

info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace GetRest.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme GetRest -destination id=81866BE1-BBBB-4A67-990A-3B0B8A613075")

.............

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening GetRest.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace GetRest.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme GetRest -destination id=81866BE1-BBBB-4A67-990A-3B0B8A613075

note: Using new build system

note: Building targets in parallel

note: Planning build

note: Using build description from disk

error: /Users/user/Documents/w_space/bo.git/getrest/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-GetRest/Pods-GetRest.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "GetRest" in project "GetRest") (in target 'GetRest' from project 'GetRest')

error: /Users/user/Documents/w_space/bo.git/getrest/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-GetRest/Pods-GetRest.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "GetRest" in project "GetRest") (in target 'GetRest' from project 'GetRest')

error: /Users/user/Documents/w_space/bo.git/getrest/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-GetRest/Pods-GetRest.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "GetRest" in project "GetRest") (in target 'GetRest' from project 'GetRest')

error: /Users/user/Documents/w_space/bo.git/getrest/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-GetRest/Pods-GetRest.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "GetRest" in project "GetRest") (in target 'GetRest' from project 'GetRest')

warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the GetRest editor. (in target 'GetRest' from project 'GetRest')



** BUILD FAILED **


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! GetRest@0.0.1 ios: `react-native run-ios`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the GetRest@0.0.1 ios script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-08-22T15_35_46_982Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What have you tried? It says that a pod is missing, have you run `pod install` from the `ios` directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

- Deleting the Pods folder
- `cd ios && pod repo update && pod install && pod update`

Comment: thanks for replaying, but it doesnt works. message: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
  In Podfile:
    RNSVG (from `../node_modules/RNSVG`) was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
      React/Core

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: Run this command in the root project directory (not IOS, the react native directory) --> `​grep -rl ​"​s.dependency 'React/Core'​"​ node_modules/ ​|​ xargs sed -i ​'​'​ ​'​s=React/Core=React-Core=g'` and then try my solution again.

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I found was to create a new RN project but with version 60. Example:

```
react-native init myNewApp --version 0.60.0
```

Then go to your project folder and run

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: This worked for me when a lot of other solutions posted on here did not.  Though I do hate not being 100% up to date with RN